# Removing lines from pgfplots plots

Tags: pgfplots

How do I remove the line segment joining (0, 0) and (1, 1) when 'twopoints' contains:

```
0 0 0
1 1 0
```

in the following example?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
]
\addplot table [only marks, x index = 0, y index = 1] {twopoints};
\addplot [only marks] coordinates {(0, 1) (1, 0)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I can't put 'table' after the square brackets in the first 'addplot', whereas I can when 'twopoints' does not have the third column (and so there is no need to write 'x index' and 'y index'.[image: The line segment]

Comment: @Rmano I see a line (I edited my post). And your suggestion worked! Thanks.

Comment: please don't edit your question so that the code no longer reflects the problem.

Comment: @RunarTrollet He hasn't edited the code at all, see the revision history.

Answer (score 1):

I am using TeXLive 2015 (the version that come with Ubuntu 16.04) and I do not see any line with your code; the result for me is:

[image: your code literally]

...with *literally* your code. Anyway, you can try to see if

```
\addplot[only marks] table [x index = 0, y index = 1] {twopoints};
```

...which is anyway more correct fixes it.